# How To Delete Rows That Have an Empty Cell In ListView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a ListView that has items in every row, but some rows have empty cells. 
How can I remove all rows that have at least one empty cell?

Comment: it wouldnt be easier if you just dont add those who are empty? how is the listview populated?

Comment: well the data extracted from json files in loop  and some of them missing parameters and i have to remove any row that have missing item .

Comment: But why can't you check for the missing items during the data extraction loop, and skip those ones to they never get added?

Answer (score 0):

While I think it is best to simply not add them, this should remove the rows with empty cells:

```
        For x = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        For y = ListView1.Items(x).SubItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If ListView1.Items(x).SubItems(y).Text = "" Then
                ListView1.Items(x).Remove()
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
```